# How to dump device tokens from Urban Airship?

Tags: ios, ruby, push, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

If I have an account that has a lot of  device tokens has been registered, How to dump device tokens from an Urban Airship accounts?

Comment: See an Ruby script example here: https://gist.github.com/dixia/5884275

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment, you can use the API:

http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/device_information.html#device-listing